# web logic request redirection

Tags: request, weblogic

I have two servers(both web logic), one in DMZ network and other server in office LAN network. currently application is running fine in office network. we want to host the same application in internet (allowed only through DMZ). So I installed web server in DMZ and wants to URL redirect from DMZ to my office server.

Basically... I wanted to redirect all my internet requests from an external server to my existing application. (internet -> DMZ -> office application).

Is there any online document which will guide me for configuring web logic request redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure the Oracle WebLogic Web Server Plugins to route requests from the web server (Apache or IIS) to the WebLogic server.

The plugins are found here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wls-plugins-096117.html

The documentation shows the step-by-step configuration:

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/overview.htm#PLGWL391